# How to disable and show a div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to disable a html div by id and then show it again, but it isn't showing any more when I disable it first.

```html
<div id="not_found">there is no command</div>
```

```js
var found = 'false';  
var newClass = window.location.href;
newClass = newClass.substring(newClass.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, 5);

$(this).each(function(){ 
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {  
        found = 'true';  
    }  
});  

if(found == 'true') {  
    $(this).show(); 
    $("#not_found").remove(); 
} else {  
    $(this).hide();  
    $("#not_found").addClass();
}
```

Comment: Use to disable in jquery code $("#not_found").attr("disabled", "disabled");       and enable  use jquery code like $("#not_found").removeAttr("disabled");

Comment: i'm fixed so i changed remove addClass to hide show :)